# How do I define a variable with 2 outputs in Python?

Tags: python

I have this problem that I can´t solve.
I have this function:

```
def ex2(tex_ori):
    let = ("a" or "A")
    text_troc = tex_ori.replace(let, "x")
    return text_troc
```

And the execution for this is:

```
text_ori = input("Write a sentence: ")
     text_1 = ex2(text_ori)
     print(text_1)
```

But the only letter being replaced is just "a".
What am I doing wrong and what should i do?

I am expecting that all letters "a" and "A" are replaced with the letter "x".
For an example:
Sentence: Hi my name is Alex.
The return should be: Hi my nxme is xlex.

Thanks for the attention and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `let = ("a" or "A")` the let variable will store only the first true statement from the two (in this case "a"). In order to replace both letters you can write it for example this way:

```
def ex2(tex_ori):
    text_troc = tex_ori.replace("a", "x")
    text_troc = text_troc.replace("A", "x")
    return text_troc

text_ori = input("Write a sentence: ")
text_1 = ex2(text_ori)
print(text_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the line `let = ("a" or "A")` is incorrect.
In Python, in this context the `or` means: "Take 'a', or, if it is `None`, take 'A'".
As 'a' is impossibly `None`, it will always be taken.

I think, what you are rather looking for is something like this:

```
let = ["a", "A"]
for l in let:
   tex_ori = tex_ori.replace(l, "x")
return tex_ori
```

Comment: Not `None` but false.